# finding text into namespaced xml elements with lxml.etree

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I try to use lxml.etree to parse an XML file and find text into elements of the XML.

XML files can be as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/
     http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
 <responseDate>2002-06-01T19:20:30Z</responseDate> 
 <request verb="ListRecords" from="1998-01-15"
      set="physics:hep"
      metadataPrefix="oai_rfc1807">
      http://an.oa.org/OAI-script</request>
 <ListRecords>
  <record>
    <header>
      <identifier>oai:arXiv.org:hep-th/9901001</identifier>
      <datestamp>1999-12-25</datestamp>
      <setSpec>physics:hep</setSpec>
      <setSpec>math</setSpec>
    </header>
    <metadata>
     <rfc1807 xmlns=
    "http://info.internet.isi.edu:80/in-notes/rfc/files/rfc1807.txt" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://info.internet.isi.edu:80/in-notes/rfc/files/rfc1807.txt
    http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/1.1/rfc1807.xsd">
    <bib-version>v2</bib-version>
    <id>hep-th/9901001</id>
    <entry>January 1, 1999</entry>
    <title>Investigations of Radioactivity</title>
    <author>Ernest Rutherford</author>
    <date>March 30, 1999</date>
     </rfc1807>
    </metadata>
    <about>
      <oai_dc:dc 
      xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" 
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ 
      http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
    <dc:publisher>Los Alamos arXiv</dc:publisher>
    <dc:rights>Metadata may be used without restrictions as long as 
       the oai identifier remains attached to it.</dc:rights>
      </oai_dc:dc>
    </about>
  </record>
  <record>
    <header status="deleted">
      <identifier>oai:arXiv.org:hep-th/9901007</identifier>
      <datestamp>1999-12-21</datestamp>
    </header>
  </record>
 </ListRecords>
</OAI-PMH>
```

For the following part we assume `doc = etree.parse("/tmp/test.xml")` where text.xml contains the xml pasted above.

First I try to find all the `<record>` elements using `doc.findall(".//record")` but it returns an empty list.

Secondly, for a given word I'd like to check if it is in the `<dc:publisher>`.
To achieve this I try first to do the same as earlier : `doc.findall(".//publisher")` but i've the same issue... I'm pretty sure all of this is linked with namespaces but I don't know how to handle them.

I've read the libxml [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html), and tried the example for `findall` method on a basic xml file (without any namespace) and it worked out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Chris has already mentioned, you can also use lxml and xpath. As xpath doesn't allow you to write the namespaced names in full like `{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record` (so-called "James Clark notation" *), you will have to use prefixes, and provide the xpath engine with a prefix-to-namespace-uri mapping.

Example with lxml (assuming you already have the desired `tree` object):

```
nsmap = {'oa':'http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/', 
         'dc':'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'}
tree.xpath('//oa:record[descendant::dc:publisher[contains(., "Alamos")]]',
            namespaces=nsmap)
```

This will select all `{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record` elements that have a descendant element `{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}dc` containing the word "Alamos".

[*] this comes from an [article](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm) where James Clark explains XML Namespaces, everyone not familiar with namespaces should read this! (even if it was written a long time ago)

Comment: That replies to my question in a nutshell! In any case I would need it, I've an additional question: is the `descendant` key word targeting the first level of children or all of them ?

Comment: From the [xpath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes): "the `descendant` axis contains the descendants of the context node; a descendant is a child or a child of a child and so on"

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer*: I am using the standard library xml.etree.ElementTree module, not the lxml library (although this is a subset of lxml as far as I know). I'm sure there is an answer which is much simpler than mine which uses lxml and XPATH, but I don't know it.

### Namespace issue

You were right to say that the problem is likely the namespaces. There is no `record` element in your XML file, but there are two `{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record` tags in the file. As the following demonstrates:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

>>> xml_string = ...Your XML to parse...
>>> e = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

# Let's see what the root element is
>>> e
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}OAI-PMH at 7f39ebf54f80>

# Let's see what children there are of the root element
>>> for child in e:
...     print child
...
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}responseDate at 7f39ebf54fc8>
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}request at 7f39ebf58050>
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}ListRecords at 7f39ebf58098>

# Finally, let's get the children of the `ListRecords` element
>>> for child in e[-1]:
...     print child
... 
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record at 7f39ebf580e0>
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record at 7f39ebf58908>
```

So, for example

```
>>> e.find('ListRecords')
```

returns `None`, whereas

```
>>> e.find('{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}ListRecords'
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}ListRecords at 7f39ebf58098>
```

returns the `ListRecords` element.

Note that I am using the `find` method since the standard library ElementTree does not have an `xpath` method.

### Possible solution

One way to solve this and to get the namespace prefix and prepend this to the tag you are trying to find. You can use

```
>>>> e.tag[:e.tag.index('}')+1]
'{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}'
```

on the root element, `e`, to find the namespace, although I'm sure there is a better way of doing this.

Now we can define functions to extract the tags we want we an optional namespace prefix:

```
def findallNS(element, tag, namespace=None):

    if namspace is not None:
        return element.findall(namepsace+tag)
    else:
        return element.findall(tag)

def findNS(element, tag, namespace=None):

    if namspace is not None:
        return element.find(namepsace+tag)
    else:
        return element.find(tag)
```

So now we can write:

```
>>> list_records = findNS(e, 'ListRecords', namespace)
>>> findallNS(list_records, 'record', namespace)
[<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record at 7f39ebf580e0>, 
<Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record at 7f39ebf58908>]
```

### Alternative solution

Another solution maybe to write a function to search for all tags which end with the tag you are interested in, for example:

```
def find_child_tags(element, tag):
    return [child for child in element if child.tag.endswith(tag)]
```

Here you don't need to deal with the namespace at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer was really clear and explanatory to deal with the namespace

Answer (score 2):

@Chris answer is very good and it will work with `lxml` too. Here is another way using `lxml` (works the same way with `xpath` instead of `find`):

```
In [37]: xml.find('.//n:record', namespaces={'n': 'http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/'})
Out[37]: <Element {http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record at 0x2a451e0>
```